# Body part is missing while sending Email with an attachment

Tags: php, email

Hello I am sending one email with pdd/doc attachment. When I click to send the email, I get an email with correct attachment but I dont get the message contents in  email body part.When I click to see show original, I can see that in original contents but not in email.
Here is my code. Can anyone help me to know how would I get them in correct place?

```
<?PHP

session_start();

$applicant_name = (isset($_POST["applicant_name"])) ? $_POST["applicant_name"] : '';
$applicant_age = (isset($_POST["age"])) ? $_POST["age"] : '';
$applicant_gender = (isset($_POST["gender"])) ? $_POST["gender"] : '';
$preferred_email = (isset($_POST["preferred_email"])) ? $_POST["preferred_email"] : '';
$MobileNo = (isset($_POST["preferred_mobile_no"])) ? $_POST["preferred_mobile_no"] : '';
$_SESSION['jobTitle'];
$_SESSION['jobId'];

$pdf_doc='';

if(isset($_FILES['document_url']['name'])){
$pdf_doc = rand() . "_" . $_FILES['document_url']['name'];
copy($_FILES['document_url']['tmp_name'], "job_docs/" . $pdf_doc);
}

$name = $applicant_name;
$email = "jyotiepr@gmail.com";
$to = "Karda <".$email.">";
$from = $preferred_email;
$subject = "Application for post : ".$_SESSION['jobTitle']."[".$_SESSION['post_id']."]";

$mainMessage = "<br/>Applicant Name :-&nbsp;" . $applicant_name . "\n\n"
    . "<br/>Email:-&nbsp;" . $preferred_email . "\n\n"
    . "<br/>Phone:-&nbsp;" . $MobileNo . "\n\n"
    . "<br/>Age:-&nbsp;" . $applicant_age . "\n\n"
    . "<br/>Gender:-&nbsp;" . $applicant_gender . "\n\n";

$fileatt = "job_docs/".$pdf_doc;
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "job_docs/".$pdf_doc;

$headers = "From: $preferred_email";

// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";         

$message = $mainMessage."This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" ."-{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n\n";


$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" ." name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" ." filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .$data . "\n\n" ."-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

// Send the email

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

header("location:we_are_hiring.php");

}

else {

    header("location:index.php");;

}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant but you have an extra semicolon here: `header("location:index.php");;`

Comment: Try to send your attachment in header not in massage.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't formatted the boundary markers correctly. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="$boundary"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain

(message body)

--$boundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="attachment.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="attachment.jpg"

(base64 attachment)

--$boundary--
```

Your code has just one hyphen before `$boundary` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed your headers with body part, seprate them to solve this issue, something like this :

```
<?PHP

session_start();

$applicant_name = (isset($_POST["applicant_name"])) ? $_POST["applicant_name"] : '';
$applicant_age = (isset($_POST["age"])) ? $_POST["age"] : '';
$applicant_gender = (isset($_POST["gender"])) ? $_POST["gender"] : '';
$preferred_email = (isset($_POST["preferred_email"])) ? $_POST["preferred_email"] : '';
$MobileNo = (isset($_POST["preferred_mobile_no"])) ? $_POST["preferred_mobile_no"] : '';
$_SESSION['jobTitle'];
$_SESSION['jobId'];

$pdf_doc='';

if(isset($_FILES['document_url']['name'])){
$pdf_doc = rand() . "_" . $_FILES['document_url']['name'];
copy($_FILES['document_url']['tmp_name'], "job_docs/" . $pdf_doc);
}

$name = $applicant_name;
$email = "jyotiepr@gmail.com";
$to = "Karda <".$email.">";
$from = $preferred_email;
$subject = "Application for post : ".$_SESSION['jobTitle']."[".$_SESSION['post_id']."]";

$mainMessage = "<br/>Applicant Name :-&nbsp;" . $applicant_name . "\n\n"
 . "<br/>Email:-&nbsp;" . $preferred_email . "\n\n"
. "<br/>Phone:-&nbsp;" . $MobileNo . "\n\n"
. "<br/>Age:-&nbsp;" . $applicant_age . "\n\n"
. "<br/>Gender:-&nbsp;" . $applicant_gender . "\n\n";

$fileatt = "job_docs/".$pdf_doc;
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "job_docs/".$pdf_doc;

$headers = "From: $preferred_email";
```

// File
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);

```
// This attaches the file
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .  " boundary=\"      {$mime_boundary}\"";         

$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n\n";


$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$headers .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" ." name=\"   {$fileattname}\"\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" ." filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .$data . "\n\n" ."-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
```

// Send the email

```
if(mail($email, $subject, $mainMessage, $headers)) {

header("location:we_are_hiring.php");

}

else {

header("location:index.php");;
```

}
?>